# python: Replace/substitute all whole-word match in a string

Tags: python, regex, django, string

Let's suppose that my string is `"#big and #small, #big-red, #big-red-car and #big"`

How can I use `re.sub(), re.match(), etc.` to replace one tag with a word?

For example, all `#big`s must be changed to BIG, but `#big-red` and `#big-red-car` shouldn't be affected.

Comment: You don't need regex for this.

Comment: Just use `replace` method of `str`.

Comment: Updated the string in my question. @Keatinge's suggestion will not work because it will replace "#big-red" to "BIG-red", which is undesirable.

Comment: @Keatinge, I've tried the space trick, but won't that fail if `#big` is at the end of the string? or if there's a comma or period after it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's define your string:

```
>>> s = "#big and #small, #big-red, #big-red-car and #big"
```

Now, let's do your replacements:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'#big([.,\s]|$)', r'#BIG\1', s)
'#BIG and #small, #big-red, #big-red-car and #BIG'
```

The regex `#big([.,\s]|$)` will match all `#big` strings that are followed by a period, a comma, a space, *or* the end-of-the-line.  If there are other characters that you consider to be acceptable after `#big`, you should add them to the regex.

#### Alternative

If we want to be a little bit fancier, we can use a look-ahead assertion, `(?=...)`, to assure that what follows `#big` is acceptable:

```
>>> re.sub(r'#big(?=[.,\s]|$)', r'#BIG', s)
'#BIG and #small, #big-red, #big-red-car and #BIG'
```

#### A test using periods and commas

To test that this works as desired when `#big` has ["a comma or period after it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491439/python-replace-substitute-all-whole-word-match-in-a-string/37491653#comment62479529_37491439), let's create a new string:

```
>>> s = "#big and #big, #big. #small, #big-red, #big-red-car and #big"
```

And, let's test it:

```
>>> re.sub(r'#big(?=[.,\s]|$)', r'#BIG', s)
'#BIG and #BIG, #BIG. #small, #big-red, #big-red-car and #BIG'
```

Answer (score 4):

This info is a category of one-directional boundary tricks.

Using a *Negative* look behind/ahead assertion(s),
within the particular direction, it will let BEGIN/END of string match,
yet not allow others to match.

This leads to some interesting scenarios of combining
negative construct's within a class, that cover an endless range
of characters, yet lets you *exclude* some individual characters within
that range.

Typical constructs to use are the *negative* classes.

`\D` - Non-Digit class
`\S` - Non-Whitespace class
`\W` - Non-Word class
`\PP` - Non-Punctuation property class
`\PL` - Non-Letters property class

Since they are used in a *negative* assertion, the inverse's are actually the
characters being sought.

`\d, \s, \w, \pP, \pL` respectively

The power comes from the fact that they can be combined within
a *class* for dramatic effects.

If individual characters are added to a class, they are excluded, not allowed.
Effectively, it creates class *subtraction*.

The rules when creating a class are:

- *Classes* of characters you want, insert it's negative (i.e. `\D`, `\PP`, etc..)
- *Individual Characters* you don't want, insert as normal (i.e. `\n`, `=`, etc..)
  This can be used as class subtraction.

Subtraction Example:  `(?![\S\r\n])` would be a lookahead *boundary* that requires
only *horizontal* whitespace, that in some engines, is represented as
the `\h` construct.

---

In your example, the boundary's would be something like this.

`(?<![\S\PP-])#big(?![\S\PP-])`

Breaking it down

```
 (?<!            # Boundary - Behind direction
      [\S\PP-]   # Need all whitespace and punctuation, but not the '-'
 )
 \#big
 (?!             # Boundary - Ahead direction
      [\S\PP-]   # Need all whitespace and punctuation, but not the '-'
 )
```

Each literal character that is *added* to the class, actually excludes
it from matching.

This is called *class subtraction*.

---

Test case

Input  `#big and #small, #big, #big, #big-red, #big-red-car and #big`

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 4 ) 
#big  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 17 , len 4 ) 
#big  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 23 , len 4 ) 
#big  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 56 , len 4 ) 
#big
```

Basically, matches these only `#big` and #small, `#big`, `#big`, #big-red, #big-red-car and `#big`